# R 3.2, GCC, and homebrew

Tags: r, gcc, homebrew, gcc4.9

I recently needed to install R 3.2 to get a package from Bioconductor working, but after I installed, I get the following error:

```
[16:16:11 20] $ r
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/gcc/4.9/libgfortran.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.0/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Sure enough, brew was set to use gcc 5, so I told brew to use the 4.9 version

```
brew switch gcc 4.9
```

which got R running, but then R would fail in the middle of a package install (specifically when I ran `biocLite('DESeq2')`.

Since then, I have tried a number of things, including trying to install gcc 4.8 (but I can't seem to get R to use it, even via `~/.R/Makevars`). Even if 4.9 is not installed, R insists on calling the path shown above.

The windows version of R seems to say 4.9 does not work with 3.2:

> R-devel temporarily used a new toolchain based on 4.9.2 gcc, put together by Duncan Murdoch using build scripts written by a contractor. However, there were too many incompatibilities with existing code, and this toolchain will not be used for R 3.2.0. See notes for details on building and testing the new toolchain.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**:
I tried installing from source, as suggested by @lmw., but it fails:

```
[11:27:55 2] $ brew install r --build-from-source
==> Installing r from homebrew/homebrew-science
==> Installing r dependency: gcc
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-5.1.0/gcc-5.1.0.tar.bz2
######################################################################## 100.0%
curl: (28) Resolving timed out after 5542 milliseconds
Trying a mirror...
==> Downloading https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-5.1.0/gcc-5.1.0.tar.bz2
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
patching file gcc/jit/Make-lang.in
==> ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.1.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gc
==> make bootstrap
==> make install
==> Caveats
GCC has been built with multilib support. Notably, OpenMP may not work:
  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60670
If you need OpenMP support you may want to
  brew reinstall gcc --without-multilib
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.1.0: 1351 files, 248M, built in 32.5 minutes
==> Installing r
==> Using Homebrew-provided fortran compiler.
This may be changed by setting the FC environment variable.
==> Downloading http://cran.rstudio.com/src/base/R-3/R-3.2.0.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
patching file src/modules/lapack/vecLibg95c.c
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.0_1 --with-libintl-prefix=/usr/local/opt/gettext --enable-memory-pro
==> make
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (survival)
make[1]: *** [recommended-packages] Error 2
make: *** [stamp-recommended] Error 2

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/homebrew):
  https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-science/issues
```

**Edit 2**:
Just for the fun of it, I tried installing `r` without the `--build-from-source` option, and it worked. See my solution below. (I think building from source may have fixed the issue with the `gcc 5` upgrade, which got things working. I am **not** going to try it (things are finally working again...why screw with it?), but I wonder if I could remove the variables I set in `~/.R/Makevars` (again, see solution below).

Comment: I'm dealing with this same issue now too!

Comment: Relevant reading: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/2286

Comment: Not sure how I missed that! Thanks @iShouldUseAName!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by [this commit](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/commit/6cb9ba4f0119af61966d598a108d289096d2c42a), with new bottles for R. Make sure you `brew update` and `brew upgrade r`.

Comment: Good to know! I wonder why this didn't work earlier, though...I was updating and upgrading this morning, but it didn't work. As what I have is working, I probably won't do this just yet...just in case =). Thanks!!

Comment: Also, it's possible that the commit is the reason why things started working...is there a way to tell whether or not it's because of what I did versus the commit? On the one hand, I don't want to select your answer as the solution as it's less a solution and more of a "it's fixed!", but at the same time, I don't want to choose another answer if the reason things are working is because of the commit.

Comment: If you reinstalled R and it was 'poured' from the bottle into `/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.0_1` then you're using the latest formula revision. Rebuilding from source should also fix things, although the revision (which adds the _1) will still trigger an upgrade (see `brew outdated`).

Comment: The issue I have is very similar but does not seem to be resolved this way.

Comment: To explain: (Comment edit timed out):  I  tried brew update followed by brew upgrade r, but I think maybe its still missing a library level?  When I run R it wants to use a library level called "6" but there is only a library level "5."  I get dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/6/libgfortran.3.dylib. But this does exist under "5."   That is, there is a /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/5/libgfortran.3.dylib (but nothing under /6/.

Answer (score 3):

Rebuilding R from source fixes the same problem for me.

brew reinstall r --build-from-source

Comment: Trying it now, but it seems to be stuck at the download...maybe it's compiling? Hopefully this works! Thanks!

Comment: The reinstall failed (I think there were other issues), but I removed `r` and tried to install with the `--build-from-source` option, which failed. (See edit in question). I do, however, think that building from source caused one of the dependencies to build from source (I don't have the command line output...things crashed, I restarted), which I think fixed some of the problems related to the gcc upgrade. If your answer turns out to be the step that fixed things, I'll choose your answer--let me know!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete fix (it uses an older gcc version), but it get's me running again:

1. `brew tap homebrew/homebrew-versions`
2. `brew install gcc48`
3. `brew install r`

   - NOTE: I ran `brew install r --build-from-source` (reinstall did not work), which rebuilt *something*, but not r (it failed). It may be partially responsible for this working. Please let me know if it is! I'd like to give @lmw credit if his answer is the reason this worked.
4. Edit `~/.R/Makevars` and add the following lines (edit paths as necessary):

   ```
   CC=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/bin/gcc-4.8
   CXX=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/bin/g++-4.8
   CFLAGS=-std=c99
   ```
5. Run `r`.
6. (If you're trying to install bioconductor)

   ```
   source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
   biocLite()
   ```